# neo4j cypher compiler error in neo4j cypher compiler 2.0.1

Tags: compiler-construction, neo4j, cypher

I am using neo4j 2.0.0-M06 . But this version has issue in when in clustering.

then i move to version 2.1.0-M01 . but got error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/cypher/internal/compiler/v2_1/spi/PlanContext
```

Try both jar:

```
 neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0-2.0.1.jar
 neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0-2.0.0.jar
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show a piece of code? You'll need `neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1-2.1.0-M01.jar` on your classpath.

Comment: yes its already in class path

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix-and-match jars like this, you need all of your Neo4j jars to be of the same version. I would suggest either using a dependency management system like Maven to make sure you always have the right Jars, or using the Neo4j server instead of Neo4j Embedded (since Neo4j Server is a stand-alone application, no worries about jar versions).

If you want to do dependency management manually, then you need to make sure that every one of your neo4j jars are of the same version, and that you do not have multiple jars with the same name but different versions on your classpath.